# Meteor: issue with iron route's url parameters

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to setup a route as follows

```
Router.configure({
    layout: 'layout',
    loadingTemplate: 'loading',
    notFoundTemplate: 'notFound'
});

Router.map(function () {
    /*
    this.route('/', {
        controller: 'MyController',
        action: 'start'
    });
    */

    this.route('/:a/:b', {
        controller: 'MyController',
        action: 'start'
    });
});
```

The Controller looks like this

```
MyController = RouteController.extend({
    template: 'barfoo',

    before: function () {
        var a = this.params.a,
            b = this.params.b;

        ...
    },
    waitOn: function () { ... },
    data: {  ... },

    start: function () {
});
```

The issue is that the before function is never called. If I do something like

```
...
this.route('/', {
    controller: 'MyController',
    action: 'start'
});
```

the before function is called. I don't see any errors in the console. I must have missed something here, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear to me that the route is never actually triggered. You should check whether the first example actually triggers any code at all.

Comment: I've updated my post, it now shows how I setup my routes

Comment: I would suggest you add some code to the start action, which for instance simply logs "start called" to the console. That way you can be sure the function has been called or not, regardless of how the route has been set up. This will help you to find the exact problem.

Comment: found the problem after reading some tutorials again, you have to define a name and a path, how stupid of me :)

Comment: Did I help you though?:P

Comment: Actually you did. The controller wasn't called so I realised that something should have been wrong with how the route path was defined. Thats why I checked that part again!